# Unable to sendViaPost to url in Axis2 1.6

Tags: java, web-services

I've created Axis2 1.6 Webservice Client, I can make wsdl2java. But, when i run my program.. It shows this error?..

```
[INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://10.53.1.187:7782//rest/UVSInterface_Extend]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: /error/error404.jsp
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.huawei.bme.winuvsinterface.UVSInterface_ExtendStub.manualRecharge(UVSInterface_ExtendStub.java:14628)
at access.KitRecharge.main(KitRecharge.java:113)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 404 Error: /error/error404.jsp
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.huawei.bme.winuvsinterface.UVSInterface_ExtendStub.manualRecharge(UVSInterface_ExtendStub.java:14628)
at access.KitRecharge.main(KitRecharge.java:113)
```

Comment: the parameters passed is not valid and it creates problem when invoking the service with null or invalid parameter..

Comment: Is it possible to catch this error somewhere and prevent printing of the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

A `404` error indicates that your target url is wrong. Make sure that you send your request to the correct service url.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, what I did in Eclipse was:

- `Stop` the servlet container (in my case, Tomcat)
- Right-click the web service Java class containing the method implementations 
  and selected `Run` -> `Run on Server`
- Saw the `Axis2 web service page` appear in the Coding View

Then ran the web service client class as a Java Application, and everything was fine

Comment: Is it possible to catch this error somewhere and prevent printing of the whole stack trace?